# Get next two words after a specified word

Tags: php

I need to get the next two words after a specified string from a predefined block of text such as:
if my word is 'author' and need to return 'John Smith' Any help would be appreciated, this is purely PHP

Comment: What about pasting in an example, so we could actually help you?

Comment: That is the issue i do not have an example...

Comment: Assuming that the "word" always exists in the string: `$string = 'this is the author john smith from chelmsford';
$data = explode(' ', $string);
echo implode(' ', array_slice($data, array_search('author', $data)+1, 2));` (quick and dirty solution)

Comment: If skrilled or I can make an example, surely you can come up with one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Tibor said... Paste the exact string you are trying to decipher...

I.e. if your string is something like:

```
Title: The Book That Never Booked
Author: Richard McPoopsalot
Published Date: 06/06/1966
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
preg_match('/(?<=Author: )\S+/i', $string, $match);
$authorName = $match[0];
echo $authorName . "is the author of that book"
```

Comment: This only gets the first name though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

`/author:\s*(\w+\s\w+)/i`

It matches the word "author:" then a space, then the next two words.  It will only capture the last two words, however.

Comment: You could also do it with a bunch of `explode()`'s, but IMO, regex might be the way to go.

Comment: I think you were going to make your non-capture group optional with a `?` but forgot. There's no real reason to make that a group. also, don't escape `:`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, based on an assumption of your input. I'd use Regular Expressions, as this is one of the things they're really good at:

```
$string = "This is a test context for author John Smith.";
preg_match('/author\\s(\\w+\\s\\w+)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Outputs:

```
John Smith
```

Comment: is it possible to return just the name not including 'author', thanks

Comment: `$matches[1]` returns only the name. So it literally outputs only `John Smith` for the above example.

Comment: Apologies, I was using $matches[0]